# I don't understand WHY numerical sort functions work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I understand that the .sort() method sorts an array alphabetically, as if it was a string. Even if your array is made up entirely of numbers.

I also understand that to sort an array numerically, the code is:

```
myArray.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a-b;
});
```

The problem is I don't understand WHY this works. The function I wrote is supposed to take two arguments, 'a' and 'b', but where are these arguments coming from? The array? How does it know to do that? Then, the function returns some number. If 'a' and 'b' were 10 and 5, respectively, my function would be returning '5'. Now I'm doing myArray.sort(5);  How the heck does that magically sort my entire array numerically???

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can read more from the spec: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.11 - it's usually the place that tells you why. Or at least the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: You can use `console.log(a + " " + b);` to inspect the values being passed to the function. Open the console then and see. E.g. `[5,8,3,4,1,9].sort(function(a,b){console.log(a+" "+b);return a-b;});`

Answer (score 6):

> The function I wrote is supposed to take two arguments, 'a' and 'b', but where are these arguments coming from?

To determine what order array elements belong in, the `Array.sort` function picks pairs of elements from your array and passes them into your comparison function as `a` and `b`. The result returned by your function determines what order the two elements get placed in - if it is negative, then it knows to put `a` before `b`; if it is positive, it knows to put `a` after `b`. The actual number doesn't matter, just whether it's negative or positive.

A somewhat less confusing way of writing your example might be:

```
function myComparisonFunction(a, b) {
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

myArray.sort(myComparisonFunction);
```

Comment: It's a good explanation though but I am still confused. You said fit picks pairs of elements but how does it picks pairs? ex. [1,10,9,4,2,5]. so, what would be the pairs? will it be in series like (1,10) - (10,9) - (9,4) or maybe like (1,10) - (1,9) - (1,4)?

Answer (score 4):

The sort function operates by (cleverly) comparing pairs of array entries. Based on the result of the comparison, it knows the order for a particular pair of values. How does it know? Because it trusts the sort callback function to return

- -1 (or any negative number) if the first entry should go before the second;
- 1 (or any positive non-zero number) if the second entry should go before the first;
- 0 if the entries are the same (meaning that the order doesn't matter<sup>*</sup>)

By repeatedly comparing pairs of array entries, and doing so systematically, the sort function eventually determines the overall correct ordering according to the inherent rules imposed by the comparator function.

The nature of the systematic process used by the JavaScript sort implementation is unspecified. It's a good bet that modern JavaScript runtimes use a fairly well-optimized [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

<sup>*</sup> when two entries in the array are *equal* according to the comparison function, two things might happen: the sort function may leave them in the order in which they originally appeared, or it may swap them. By the simple logic of the sort process, either of those actions are OK; if you're sorting a list of names, and "Thomas" appears twice, then it doesn't matter which "Thomas" is first and which is second since the strings are identical and indistinguishable. However, if a sort comparator function is plucking properties from pairs of objects, sometimes it *does* matter that entries remain in original order if their comparison returns `0`.  A sort function that ensures that behavior is called **stable**. Whether a JavaScript implementation is stable or not is undefined by the spec.

Comment: I think this makes the most sense to me, thank you. The sort function works by comparing two values in the array and determing it's order by whether it's greater or less than the other. By default, .sort() just does it alphabetically, unless we specify with a function how to do it. Hope this is correct!

Comment: @taykcrane yes, that is exactly right. The built-in behavior is to sort as strings. The way you tell it to sort differently is by providing a comparator function; that way the sort routine can say "OK how about these two?  Which should come first?" and the comparator returns the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This comparator function, as used in `Array.sort` ([ES5 spec.](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.11), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)), should return a *number* where..

- if a < b, return *less than 0*
- if a > b, return *more than 0*
- else (a == b) return *0*

So, let's look at some cases:

```
a     b     a-b    meaning (see above)
----  ----  ----   ------
10    5     5      "a > b"
5     10    -5     "a < b"
5     5     0      "a == b"
```

The comparator function *defines ordering* between elements which is used in a [Comparison Sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort):

> A comparison sort is a type of sorting algorithm that only reads the list elements through a single abstract comparison operation (often a "less than or equal to" operator or a three-way comparison [aka "comparator"]) that determines which of two elements should occur first in the final sorted list.

(Note: The sort by `Array.sort` is *not* guaranteed to be [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).)

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I know. I fixed the lie at the bottom - need to refresh/correct my "knowledge" every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I'm doing myArray.sort(5);

That's not true. Passing in a function that (sometimes) returns `5` is not at all the same thing as passing in `5`.

What happens is, you pass in a function that `sort` can call whenever it needs to know which of two values should be considered greater. `sort` will pass two arguments to that function. If the function returns a negative value, that means "the first argument is less than the second argument"; if it returns zero, that means "the two arguments should be considered equal"; if it returns a positive value, that means "the first argument is greater than the second argument". (This might seem a bit hackish and arbitrary — and maybe it is — but it has a long history in C-like languages.) So, for numeric comparisons, it's convenient to just return `a-b`, since that meets these requirements.

Note that you cannot predict exactly which comparisons `sort` will decide to perform, so you need to make sure to pass in a function that behaves consistently. For example, if your function says that 1 is less than 2 and 2 is less than 3, then your function also needs to say that 2 is greater than 1, that 3 is greater than 2, that 1 is less than 3, and that 3 is greater than 1. Otherwise, you might get random-seeming results.

(You may be interested in [the MDN page on `Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), by the way. It gives a number of other examples, which might help clarify this for you.)

Answer (score 1):

So it runs through and applies whatever algorithm it wants to sort the values in your array.  All it needs to know is how to tell which one is "bigger" or which one should be forward indexed.

I guess it helps to have some more familiarity with how javascript works.  With javascript you can assign variables as functions and as such you can pass functions as parameters.  It comes in handy in situations like this and for asynchronous callbacks (if you've played with jquery you've likely seen this in ajax calls and they're called for after various transformations are completed...like if you want one element to move 500px and then as soon as it completes it you move it down 500px, you put the down move function in the call back).

long story short, the a and b values come from your array, which values it pulls out are up to the sort function.

the awesome thing about the comparison function of sort is say you have an object that looks like this:

```
sales:[{sale:{"brand":"Nike", "person":"Eric", "total":5000}}, {sale:{...}}]
```

you can do use a sorting function to sort by brand then total like this:

```
sales.sort(function(a,b){
    if (a.brand==b.brand){
       return a.brand>b.brand ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
       return a.total-b.total;
});
```

I tend to think stuff like that is really neat...it lets the language use the most efficient sorting algorithm it feels like using and all you have to do is show it how to determine if one is "bigger" than another.

Answer (score 0):

a and b two consecutive values in array to compare
and subtraction can be 0, less than zero and greater than zero.. 
if greater than zero, it means prior element is larger so it needs to be pushed further down
if it is less than zero, it means it needs not to be pushed down..

Comment: So I understand that, but what part of my function is telling it to push down, not push down, etc. It just seems so arbitrary to me.

Comment: it is probably implemented in the javascript engine, we would have to write a similar function to show the concept.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're NOT doing `myArray.sort(5);`, because you pass a function (that is used to guide the sorting algorithm), not a number.